# Artisan command queue work doesn't run in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Well i have this issue working with queues in Laravel, i'm using ubuntu 18.04 in wsl 2, when i run this command nothing happens.
[image]

Any idea of where is the problem?

Edit: This is the code where i dispatch the job

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\Cortes;


class CortesController extends Controller 
{
  public function Cortes()
  {
    Cortes::dispatch();
    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you dispatch the job?

Comment: Of course, take a look

Comment: Are you using the database driver for your queue? If so, you need to update it inside your env.

Comment: Did you run the migration to create the job table? `php artisan queue:table` once you do that and run the migration `php artisan migrate`

If you do have a queue table is it populated?

Comment: Thanks for the help but a friend told me that this is a normal behavior, it's just like Juan told, the table doesn't have jobs pending, however, thanks all of you.